# What does "failed" mean in a completed Spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have jobs that repartition the huge datasets in parquet format and the file system used is `s3a` (S3).

Browsing through the Spark UI, I stumbled upon a job which has uncompleted tasks but the job marked is successful.

The different categories of jobs: i) Active, ii) Completed, iii) Failed.
I am unable to deduce the reason for this failed job, nor I am able to assert whether this was actually a failed one, given that there is another category for failed jobs.

[image]

How do I resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: If you click on the 87's second line, its a link to stages pages and points to stages associated with the job. Then you can drill down to tasks and in the left most column, there will be a reason (stacktrace) noted for the failure. If you need further help with this, you could post those images so that our community can better answer your questions!

Comment: @Sai
Can you help me with my problem: whether the job was done or failed?

Comment: @Sai
Also, which community are you talking about?